# pdfkit - An A4 html page does not print into an A4 pdf

Tags: python, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit, html-to-pdf, python-pdfkit

I have reproduced my problem below :

1. I draw a 210x297 rectangle on a web page

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <style>
   div.rectangle {
     border: solid 1px;
     width: 210mm;
     height: 297mm;
   }
   </style>
   <head>
   </head> 
   <body> 
   <div class="rectangle">
     <img/>
   </div>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. I transform this html document to pdf with pdfkit in Python

   ```
   import pdfkit

   options = {
       'page-size':'A4',
       'encoding':'utf-8', 
       'margin-top':'0cm',
       'margin-bottom':'0cm',
       'margin-left':'0cm',
       'margin-right':'0cm'
   }

   pdfkit.from_file('test.html', 'test.pdf', options=options)
   ```
3. I obtain a pdf file with a rectangle at the top left corner whose size is roughly 5 times too small...

I would really appreciate if you can have a look !

Comment: What OS do you have? I have the same issue on the macOS.

Answer (score 6):

For me manual set up of the DPI works as workaround:

```
options={'page-size':'A4', 'dpi':400}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try to disable shrinking through the options as below

```
options = { 'disable-smart-shrinking': ''}
```